# Is there is any way to directly access files from video gallery?

Tags: ios

I want to know is there are any way to doing this (talking about iOS): Choose video from Video gallery, store its 'URI'. And then access this video using this URI directly?

For example, on Android I can pick video, remember its filename, and with file system load it using this filename.

I don't want to store it is in my application cache folder or something else, that will duplicate data on device.

Is there is a way to do such thing on iOS?

Comment: Not direct to the file, but you can get the asset URL and use the assets library.

Comment: So asset URL can do for me what I want? Storing this asset url can give me ability to access video when app will restarted, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you just need to supply the URL to the assets library. Note that the user may have deleted the asset so you need to deal with that...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at all of the "Bookmark" [methods of NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

They give you the ability to find the underlying file, even if it's moved around when your app is closed.

From the docs:

> A bookmark provides a persistent reference to a file-system resource. When you resolve a bookmark, you obtain a URL to the resource’s current location. A bookmark’s association with a file-system resource (typically a file or folder) usually continues to work if the user moves or renames the resource, or if the user relaunches your app or restarts the system.